# How to skip first two lines of a CSV file with a for loop?

Tags: php

I would like to read each lines of a CSV file except for the first two lines of the file.
Right now this is my code:

```
for ($j = 0; $j <= count($customers) - 1; $j++)
```

It works if I delete the first line of my CSV file, but I really need to keep it.

Comment: How are you currently reading the CSV file?

Comment: Use [`continue`](http://php.net/continue): `if ($j <= 2) continue;`

Comment: Put the count outside the loop statement, as it is evaluated on each iteration, which is in most situation wasted performance.

Comment: I would argue that all the answers saying set j=2 to start are just wrong.   The OP has not provided enough information to make this determination.   We need to know where the file is being read - before the loop, in the loop, etc.   This makes a huge difference in how the question can be answered.

Comment: i have tried $j=2, but it doesn't work. i just want the proram to skip the first two lines of the file entirely, as if they don't even exist.

Comment: You need to give us more code/info

Comment: As I mentioned above, @user3560769, you need to provide us with more information.   WHERE / HOW ARE YOU READING THE FILE??

Comment: Additionally, for info - you can't just "skip" parts of the file.   You read the first line, do nothing with it.   Read the second line, do nothing with it.   Then you read additional lines and process them as normal.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
for ($j = 2; $j <= count($customers) - 1; $j++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for ($j = 2; $j <= count($customers) - 1; $j++)
```

or

this:

```
for ($j = 0; $j <= count($customers) - 1; $j++)  {
    if($j < 2 ) {
       continue;
    }
}
```

I guess this is what you are looking for..